# Equivalence of continuity in systems of neighbourhoods and topologies?

Tags: general-topology, continuity

In a topology course we showed a statement about the equivalence of continuity in terms of systems of neighbourhoods and in terms of topologies. We showed that a function $f\colon X\to Y$ on some topological spaces $(X,\mathcal X)$ and $(Y,\mathcal Y)$ with their induced systems $\nu(\mathcal X)$ and $\nu(\mathcal Y)$ of neighbourhoods (definitions and theorems below) is $\nu(\mathcal X)$-$\nu(\mathcal Y)$-continuous, iff $f^{-1}(V)\in\mathcal X$ for every $V\in\mathcal Y$.

Now, I was wondering whether the same equivalence can be proven in a single point. More precisely, I was wondering whether

> $f$ is $\nu(\mathcal X)$-$\nu(\mathcal Y)$-continuous in $x\in X$, iff $f^{-1}(V)\in\mathcal X$ for all $V\in\mathcal Y$ with $f(x)\in V$.

The "$\Leftarrow$" direction turned out to be pretty easy: For every $N\in\nu(\mathcal Y,f(x))$ we have $f(x)\in V\subseteq N$ for some $V\in\mathcal Y$, and thus $x\in f^{-1}(V)\subseteq f^{-1}(N)$, where $f^{-1}(V)\in\mathcal X$ by assumption. It follows that $f^{-1}(N)\in\nu(\mathcal X,x)$ showing that $f$ is $\nu(\mathcal X)$-$\nu(\mathcal Y)$-continuous in $x$.

However, I get stuck in the "$\Rightarrow$" direction, and I can't imagine it actually being that hard to prove. **Does anyone know a proof of this statement or reference proving it or a counter example disproving it?**

---

> **Definition.** Let $X$ be a set. A family $\mathcal T\subseteq2^X$ of subsets of $X$ is called *topology on $X$*, if $\mathcal T$ contains $\emptyset$, $X$, arbitrary unions of elements of $\mathcal T$ and finite intersections of elements of $\mathcal T$.

> **Definition.** Let $X$ be a set. A family $\{N(x)\}_{x\in X}$ of non-empty subsets $N(x)\subseteq2^X$ is called *system of neighbourhoods on $X$*, if for every $x\in X$ the following conditions are satisfied.
>
> - Every $N\in N(x)$ contains $x$
> - $N(x)$ contains all finite intersections of elements of iteself.
> - $N(x)$ contains all supersets of elements of iteself.
> - $N^\circ\in N(x)$ for every $N\in N(x)$, where $N^\circ:=\{z\in X\mathbin\vert N\in N(z)\}$ for every $N\subseteq X$.

> **Definition.** Let $X$ and $Y$ be two sets and let $\mathcal N_X=\{N_X(x)\}_{x\in X}$ and $\mathcal N_Y=\{N_Y(y)\}_{y\in Y}$ be two systems of neighbourhoods on $X$ and $Y$ respectively. A function $f\colon X\to Y$ is called $\mathcal N_X$-$\mathcal N_Y$-continuous in $x\in X$, if we have $f^{-1}(N)\in N_X(x)$ for every $N\in N_Y(f(x))$. The function $f$ is called $\mathcal N_X$-$\mathcal N_Y$-continuous, if it is $\mathcal N_X$-$\mathcal N_Y$-continuous everywhere.

> **Theorem.** Every topology $\mathcal T$ on $X$ induces a system $\nu(\mathcal T):=\{\nu(\mathcal T,x)\}_{x\in X}$ of neighbourhoods on $X$, where $\nu(\mathcal T,x):=\{N\subseteq X\mathbin\vert x\in U\subseteq N\text{ for some }U\in\mathcal T\}$.

> **Theorem.** For every subset $N\subseteq X$ of some topological space $(X,\mathcal T)$ we have $N^\circ=\bigcup_{\mathcal T\ni U\subseteq N}U$. A subset $N\subseteq U$ is open (i.e. $N\in\mathcal T$), iff $N=N^\circ$, wehere $^\circ$ is defined in terms of $\nu(\mathcal T)$, i.e. $N^\circ=\{z\in X\mathbin\vert z\in N(x\}.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question properly, then the following would be a counterexample.

Let
$$
f(x)=\cases{x & if $\ x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}\ $,\\
        \left(\,\min\big\{d\in\mathbb{N}\,\big| \,d\vert x\vert \in\mathbb{N} \big\}\,\right)^{-1}& if $\ x\in\mathbb{Q}\setminus\{0\}\ $,\\
0& if $\ x=0\ $.}
$$
Then $\ f\ $ is $\ \nu(\mathcal{X})$-$ \nu(\mathcal{X})\ $ continuous at $\ x=0\ $, where $\  \mathcal{X}\ $ is the standard topology of $\ \mathbb{R}\ $, but $\ f^{-1}\left(\left(-\epsilon,\epsilon\right)\right)\ $ is not open for any $\ \epsilon>0\ $.  If $\ 2^n>\epsilon^{-1}\ $, for instance, and $\ \frac{3^m}{2^n}>\epsilon\ $, then $\ f\left(\frac{3^m}{2^n}\right)=\frac{1}{2^n}\in\left(-\epsilon,\epsilon\right) \ $, but every neighbourhood of $\ \frac{3^m}{2^n}\ $ contains an irrational number $\ x\ $such that $\ f(x)=x\not\in\left(-\epsilon,\epsilon\right)\ $.

Comment: I just checked this through and this function actually is a counter example to my claim. That is wild! I would have never thought that for two equivalent definitions of topologies on a set the intuitive definitions for continuity in a point could be different. Thank you :)